# using microtime to store bids

Tags: php, codeigniter

Trying to store a microtime, every time a user bids according to the local time GMT in database. trying this code below but its just storing as 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in the database.

function create($user_bid){

```
    $this->db->set('bid', $user_bid);

    $this->db->set('microtime',microtime(TRUE));


    $query= $this->db->insert('products');


    $this->load->view('bidding');
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Use an int or varchar field, and not a date field in your mysql tables.